# Java ExecutorsService submit a FutureTask get on Future returns null

Tags: java, future, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, futuretask

I have this snippet.

```
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    final Runnable runnable = ()->{System.out.println("Inside runnable run method");};
    final Callable<String>callable = ()->{System.out.println("Inside callable call method");return "callable";};
    final FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask<>(()->{System.out.println("CallableInFutureTask");},"JOHN");
    final FutureTask f1 = (FutureTask)executor.submit(callable);
    final FutureTask f2 = (FutureTask)executor.submit(futureTask);
    final FutureTask f3 = (FutureTask)executor.submit(runnable);
    System.out.println("f1 = " + f1+" "+f1.isDone()+" "+f1.get());
    System.out.println("FutureTask Reference Object: "+futureTask.isDone()+" "+futureTask.get());
    System.out.println("f2 = "+f2.isDone()+" "+f2.get());
    System.out.println("f3 = " + f3+" "+f3.isDone()+" "+f3.get());        
    executor.shutdown();
```

The f1 and f3 Future variables is returning the correct values of its get method but the FutureTask past it to the Executors the f2 is returning null why is this? Even the futureTask reference is returning the correct value "JOHN" for the get method but why is this? Maybe because i am passing a FutureTask? I dont get it.

I just thought that f2 and futureTask references would return the same value. Sorry if this question is simple thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit a `FutureTask` to a `ExecutorService` it is treated as a `Runnable` so the the `Future` you get from the `submit` method would have the value `null` as the `Runnable` instances don't return any result.

Since the `FutureTask` implements the `Runnable` interface this method of the `ExecutorService` is called `submit(Runnable task)` so the `Runnable` you are wrapping in the `FutureTask` constructor is actually submitted to the `ExecutorService` and hence you get null on the invocation of `f2.get()`.

But when you are calling the `get()` on the `FutureTask` reference you are then getting back the value you supplied as the second parameter once the `Runnable` has *completed its execution* (when you submitted the task earlier in the `ExecutorService`).

You can also verify this by *not submitting* the `futureTask` in the `ExecutorService`, then if you try to invoke get on the `futureTask` variable the `get` call will block indefinitely as the `Runnable` has not been executed.

```
 // Returning "JOHN" when the supplied Runnable is completed execution.
 System.out.println("FutureTask Reference Object: "+futureTask.isDone()+" "+futureTask.get());
```

This is as per the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#FutureTask(java.lang.Runnable,%20V)):

> Creates a FutureTask that will, upon running, execute the given
>   Runnable, and arrange that get will return the given result on
>   successful completion.

Comment: holy crap you are correct thanks mate best regards from Venezuela

Answer (score 1):

It's correct with the returns. f1 has a return, but f2 and f3 haven't. And null stands here for **void**